# Move PictureBox from one form to another form C#

Tags: c#, winforms

im actually trying to program in C# and want to move an image from a pictureBox1 from Form1 to another pictureBox1 of Form2.

I did following

In Form1.cs:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Load("C:\\Users\\img_0.bmp");
        }
```

In Form1.Designer: change from private to public

```
public System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
```

In Form2.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Form1.pictureBox1.Image;
        }
```

But i get  this error: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.pictureBox1'

Can somebody help me please? :)

Comment: You should pass the instance of Form1 to Form2. There are endless duplicates on stack overflow, please search for it.

Comment: Your Form2 constructor should look like this: `public Form2(Image useImage) {...}` Store that information with a variable so when the button is clicked, you use your variable to update the pictureBox1.Image property.

Answer (score -1):

Although it is not appropriate to do it this way, but, Yes, this is possible.

First create the picture box in external class file like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
    }
}
```

Then add it into your 1st form, let's say another button click event will open another form. So you will have to first remove the picturebox, which will allow the 2nd form to use it.

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Add(Class1.pb1);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(Class1.pb1);
    Form3 f = new Form3();
    f.ShowDialog();
    this.Controls.Add(Class1.pb1);
}
```

Then, while you open the next form, add the picturebox and when the next form is closing, remove it.

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Add(Class1.pb1);
    this.FormClosing += Form3_FormClosing;
}

private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(Class1.pb1);
}
```

There, you have move the picturebox from 1st form to 2nd form and then back to 1st form.